# C++ program using Caffe with CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, caffe

I try to run a program with Cuda.

To build Caffe and make runtest was fine.

But I got the error messages when I compile a simple code.

Of course, I had link include and library.

> /usr/local/include/caffe/util/device_alternate.hpp:34:23: fatal error:
>   cublas_v2.h: No such file or directory

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of the Cuda you are using. You might need to reinstall CUDA.

If after you re-install the cuda, and still get the error:

In order to fix the cublas error, you will have to include the path to your cuda folder.

1. `locate cublas_v2.h` -- this should give you the path to your cuda installation
2. `export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/your/cuda/path:$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`

Your cuda path will look something like: `/opt/cuda-X.0/include`

Hope this helps.